# SquirrelSQL access more databases in one SQL script

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, squirrel-sql

It's probably a trivial question but I wasn't able to find any solution. The following script:

```
use Database1
go
...

use Database2
go
...
```

works in SQL Server Management Studio but not in SquirrelSQL 3.5.0 (jTDS Microsoft SQL driver) - **use:** *invalid SQL statement*.

What's wrong? Should I enable something in Squirrel options? (Both databases are located on the same server.)

Comment: Squirrel uses JDBC to access databases, and AFAIK JDBC connections point to a database, not to a server, so I don't think you can do that, you have to have two separate connections for the two databases.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I tried to change the connection string to: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:1433 (without the /database at the end) but it didn't help.